# How to code no duplicates and sorted in python?

Tags: python

I am trying to code a function which can index no duplicates and sorted, and return to a list, here is what I wrote:

```
def get_common_words_used(sentence, common_words):
    new_list = ""
    for item in sentence:
        if item == common_words:
            new_list = new_list.lower()
            new_list = [item] + new_list
            new_list.sort()
    return new_list

def test_get_common_words_used():
    print(get_common_words_used("Easy come, easy go go go", ["a", "go", "i", "on", "the"]))
```

This prints Nothing

But my expected output is  `['go']`

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

This should help.

```
def get_common_words_used(sentence, common_words):
    new_list = []
    for item in set(sentence.split()):   #Split by space and use set to remove duplicates.
        if item in common_words:
            new_list.append(item)
    return sorted(new_list)               #sort

def test_get_common_words_used():
    print(get_common_words_used("Easy come, easy go go go", ["a", "go", "i", "on", "the"]))

test_get_common_words_used()
```

**Output:**

```
['go']
```

Comment: If I want them all in lower case, do I just add it into the return function?

Comment: `new_list.append(item.lower())
` ?

Answer (score 1):

**First you need to split the given string into words then you need to check whether that item present in given list or not**

```
def get_common_words_used(sentence, common_words):
    new_list = []
    for item in sentence.split(" "):# You need to split the string into words by space
        if item in common_words:
            new_list.append(item)
    new_list    = list(set(new_list))# List will have the duplicates
    new_list.sort()
    return new_list

def test_get_common_words_used():
    print(get_common_words_used("Easy come, easy go go go", ["a", "go", "i", "on", "the"]))
```

**Output:**

```
['go']
```